# Powerpoint language does not follow slide master

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, language

I have a Slide Master with a textbox for the title and another textbox below. Both of the textboxes are set to use *English (U.S.)*.

Whenever I create a new slide based on that master, the language of the textboxes is *Spanish (Argentina)*.

Is it expected that the language of textboxes in a Slide Master is not kept in slides?

Is there any way of changing this behavior?

**EDIT** This question has a follow-up one

[Setting the language of a Powerpoint presentation](https://superuser.com/questions/694858/setting-the-language-of-a-powerpoint-presentation)

Answer (score 1):

New slides seem to assume the language that the entire presentation's set to, regardless of the language of the placeholders on the masters/layouts.

Then in some versions, PPT may change the language based on your keyboard (ie, windows settings).  That's controlled by Options | Advanced | Automatically switch keyboard ...etc.
Try removing the checkmark there.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to change "the language that the entire presentation's set to"? I have [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=powerpoint+set+presentation+language), but I have found workarounds for changing the language of currently existing placeholders (and also VBA code for changing *all* text), not for anything to be inserted in the future. I might use it after the presentation is finished, but it is still a workaround, and it is incomplete (I might forget doing that after finishing, or someone else might not do it in shared work). The checkmark you mention is already cleared.

Comment: I've followed up there with a bit of code that should help.  And a warning about using it. ;-)

Comment: By the way, if you want something a bit more user-friendly than running VBA, and more complete than most of the VBA scraps you find on the net, I've got a commercial add-in that does the job.  http://www.pptools.com/languageselector

Comment: >> Is it expected that the language of textboxes in a Slide Master is not kept in slides?   Yes, it's expected and a feature, not a flaw.  It enables users to enter text in a language other than that specified in the slide master/placeholders.

>> Is there any way of changing this behavior?  I've explained how to change the behavior elsewhere, so I guess the answer is Yes.  If I'm misunderstanding the question, let me know.

Comment: You are right, answer to 1) should be "Yes". But then Is there any way of changing this behavior? I guess it is "No, but you can anyway take a workaround". And since you answered "*seem* to assume", I understood that it was based on experience, not on specific documentation...

Comment: I don't know of any way to change the behavior other than removing the commands for changing the language from the ribbon so users can't access them.  As far as my "seems to" ... yes, that's based on my experience, but sometimes PPT changes its behavior just because I do things in a different order from they way someone else does them.  I try not to assume that what I've seen is necessarily universal.